# Shiny - How not to select any option in radioButtons?

Tags: r, radio-button, shiny

How can I **not** to select any option in radioButtons?

From this [doc](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/radioButtons.html):

> selected  The initially selected value (if not specified then defaults
>   to the first value)

But I don't want to select anything when the page is loaded. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documentation:](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/radioButtons.html)

> If you need to represent a "None selected" state, it's possible to
>   default the radio buttons to have no options selected by using
>   selected = character(0). However, this is not recommended, as it gives
>   the user no way to return to that state once they've made a selection.
>   Instead, consider having the first of your choices be c("None
>   selected" = "").

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think it is odd to have the radio buttons but having them not selected.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Wasn't that your question?

Comment: i mean the logic of my program is odd for having radio buttons and not select any of it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Glad you were able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience if i don't specify the "Selected" most browsers just don't select anything, they don't select the first one like the doc suggests.